# Placing notices on cars in same-residence parking lot

Tags: landlord, tenant, wisconsin, notice

A large portion of backstory is directly connected with [this question from 2016](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/9126/what-restrictions-limitations-can-take-place-to-apartment-parking-mid-lease).

Briefly put, permit-required parking stalls are continuously being occupied by people without permits. However, when there's an abundance of vehicles parked without permits, we try to call the property manager to do something. To no surprise, this has lead to no known resolution. The only time the lot is claimed to be monitored is for 3 hours during Thursday evenings, about 8 weeks of the year (during an event that happens across the street). We pay an additional $5/month for a parking permit, which was offered to resolve the parking issues by "monitoring, ticketing, and towing vehicles," but it seems like this permit doesn't actually yield anything.

**Problem**:
The issue now is that they're still opting to do absolutely nothing to alleviate the parking issues. One approach was to write warning notices to place on vehicles that were illegally parked— the rule of the parking permit is it must be displayed at all times in the rear-view mirror. Although it would be difficult to keep up with vehicles every day, the hope was to bring to the vehicle owner's attention that their vehicle should not be parked there.

This notice simply mentions that their car is illegally parked, that their license plate has been noted, and that they're at risk of being towed, pursuant to the statute that is posted on the sign in front of each parking stall. Additionally, if they have any questions, they can contact the property manager for more information.

Today, the property manager questioned these notices that people were calling in about. He decided to file a police complaint, which claims that we are not permitted to place notices on vehicles on private property. In addition, he's claiming that we need to have an in-person meeting to "discuss this situation and your future at the community". He also states that if we don't cooperate, he will "act accordingly." It's suggestive of trying to evict, but it seems like a lot of smoke due to it being a minor issue as a direct result of their lack of effort to resolve an issue that's been going on for 4+ years now.

**Question**:

- Since we are residents of the apartment complex, does that impact the legality of being able to place parking notices?
- Does the negligence of not resolving the parking issues open any doors for contesting the complaint (or anything really)?

Both sides agree that the notices aren't believed to be impersonating staff. We *are* reaching out to a handful of landlord-tenant lawyers to review these parking issues as a whole. One, off-the-record, mentioned there is a chance for breach of contract because the paid parking isn't being guaranteed. As this could be a few days or weeks to coordinate a meeting with a lawyer, I thought I'd get some initial insight here for me to review ahead of time.